# Token Mismatch Exception in Laravel 5.5.13 even though {{ csrf_field() }} is added in form

Tags: php, laravel, csrf-token

I am facing Token Mismatch Exception in Laravel 5.5.13 Legacy code base. The application was working until the error occurs. I have fixed that error and it started showing `Token Mismatch Exception`. I have also added `{{ csrf_field() }}` in form. When I check with laravel debug, I saw the csrf token in form request but still showing Token Mismatch Exception.
[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuVt0.png)

Comment: Checkout your session driver and make sure that session is working just fine by storing into it and retrieving something or simply by persisting a session within your browser

Answer (score 0):

Try :

`{!! csrf_token() !!}`

Instead of:

`{{ csrf_field() }}`